# testing AWS hello world lambda container with RIE hangs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy a simple hello-world AWS lambda function as a container image. I'm at the stage of testing the function following the instructions found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-test.html.

However, I'm not able to trigger the function using the built-in RIE. I must be missing something very basic. Here are the details:

Handler code (app.py):

```
def handler(event, context):
    return 'Hello from AWS Lambda using Python'
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY app.py ./

CMD ["app.handler"]
```

Docker build:

```
(venv) test % docker build -t mytest:latest .      
[+] Building 0.9s (7/7) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                             
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8                                                                                                                                                       0.8s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 27B                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [1/2] FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8@sha256:086ab31133d855f5a935ae3cf6f592cad416a7415cdb7a3f0b25f5e15b7d4ea5                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => resolve public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8@sha256:086ab31133d855f5a935ae3cf6f592cad416a7415cdb7a3f0b25f5e15b7d4ea5                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [2/2] COPY app.py ./                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:c90a438594cad5f940b78986f91e8c135a50f68a1bc0c17201a02a67edc1cfff                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/mytest:latest                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
(venv) test %
```

Docker run:

```
(venv) test % docker run -p 9000:8080 mytest:latest
22 May 2022 20:55:34,516 [INFO] (rapid) exec '/var/runtime/bootstrap' (cwd=/var/task, handler=)
```

Attempt to trigger the handler:

```
~ % curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}' --http0.9 --output - -v

Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:9000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> POST /2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 2
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* Closing connection 0
```

At this point the HTTP request just hangs until it eventually times out. There is no output on the docker container console either.

My docker runtime (MacOS 12.3.1):

```
(venv) test % docker --version
Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396
(venv) test %
```

Comment: Try `-XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations"`

Comment: yeah, sorry that was a typo in my OP. I had been experimenting with several things and I used a later test example when writing the OP. But yes, I had started with the request as written in the documentation but the behavior is the same:

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9000/2015-03-31/functions/function/invocations" -d '{}' --http0.9 --output - -v

I will update the OP to remove the confusion on that point.

Comment: I may have a breakthrough here...it appears port 9000 was being listened by a different process on my host so my curl triggers were getting captured by the other process instead of the lambda function container. I tried the test again by mapping to port 9090 instead of 9000 and it appears to work. But shouldn't I have gotten an error when the docker container started due to the mapped port being already in use?

Comment: Yes you should've. What was the process in question? Glad you got it sorted :) asking about the port was going to be my next question.

Comment: Port 9000 was being used by "Python -m ipykernel_launcher" which most likely for Jupyter notebooks in VS Code. I'm still at a loss as to why I wasn't notified of the conflict when I launched the container.